# Consolidating two lines of nodejs code into one

Tags: javascript, node.js, module

I've been having a bit of trouble with some javascript code. I was wondering if stackoverflow could help out.

I have this module...

```
var errorObject = (function() {
errorObject = {};
errorObject.location = "Unknown";
errorObject.schema = mongoose.model('Error', {
      id: { type: String, index: true },
      device: { type: String, index: true },
      file: { type: String },
      meta: { type: String },
      data: { type: String },
      type: { type: String }
    });
errorObject.callback = function (err, level, msg, meta) {  
      var data = {
          device: "test",
          file: errorObject.location,
          meta: JSON.stringify(meta),
          data: msg,
          type: level
      };  
      new errorObject.schema(data).save(function(err, data){
        if(!err){
            console.log("Saved");
        }
      });
  };
  return errorObject;
})();

module.exports = {Logger: errorObject}
```

Which I am trying to use to track information in all my other node files like so...

```
var Logger = new require('../lib/models').Logger;
Logger.location = __filename;
```

My question is, how do I make those two import lines above into one line? I have to import the logging into all of my .js files and I would love to be as concise as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An assignment in Javascript returns the assignment outside of the block it's in, so you can do the following:

```
(x = 5).toString()
"5"
```

So you should be able to similarly do

```
(Logger = new require('../lib/models').Logger).location = __filename;
```

[edit] See comment below, I removed the "var" because it scopes the variable into the parenthesis.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. You have to take the var out of the line to get it to work. Like this...   (Logger = new require('../lib/models').Logger).location = __filename;

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up, I fixed the code in the answer!

Answer (score 1):

From within your logger module, export a function that returns your actual logger object, and call this function when requiring it. Basically something like this:

```
module.exports = function (location) {
  return new Logger(location, ...); // Whatever ...
};
```

And then:

```
var logger = require('../lib/models/logger')(__filename);
```

IMHO this is even more concise than the syntax you are using right now, although it means rewriting some parts of your module.

PS: Generally speaking, your code doesn't look very node-ish, instead, you seem to come from the browser (as you are using an IIFE and so on). As a general advise, you should read more about CommonJS modules and how Node's module system works. It's not necessary to use IIFEs.

Comment: I actually am pretty new to nodejs. Thanks for the advice. I'll look into the proper module format.

Answer (score 1):

You could just make a proper constructor and pass the value into it:

```
function Logger(location) {
  if (!(this instanceof Logger))
    return new Logger(location);

  this.location = location || 'Unknown';
  this.schema = mongoose.model('Error', {
    id: { type: String, index: true },
    device: { type: String, index: true },
    file: { type: String },
    meta: { type: String },
    data: { type: String },
    type: { type: String }
  });
}
Logger.prototype.callback = function(err, level, msg, meta) {
  var data = {
    device: 'test',
    file: errorObject.location,
    meta: JSON.stringify(meta),
    data: msg,
    type: level
  };  
  this.schema(data).save(function(err, data) {
    if (!err)
      console.log('Saved');
  });
};

module.exports = { Logger: Logger };
```

Then use it like:

```
var Logger = require('../lib/models').Logger(__filename);

// ...

Logger.callback(....);
```

Comment: This is actually how this should be done. The schema was being weird imported into the callback, so I just went with the simpler answer below. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it like this

```
(var Logger = new require('../lib/models').Logger).location = __filename;
```